# How to use Embeddable with encapsulated collection

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have an `User`, and I want this user to have a set of tasks. I created a class called TaskCollection that encapsulates this set. However, I am not able to persist it. An User can have many tasks and the same task can be associated to many users (manyToMany)

Any advice in how to make it work?

I do need to have the set encapsulated as TaskCollection and I am using Ebean/Play 2.

```
@Entity 
public class User extends Model {

    @Id 
    public Long id;

    @Embedded 
    public TaskCollection taskCollection = new TaskCollection();
}

@Embeddable 
public class TaskCollection {

    @Id 
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public final Set<Task> collection;
}

@Entity
public class Task extends Model {

    @Id 
    public Long id;
}
```

Comment: The embeddable does not have an ID, so remove it from there. Also you did not say what is the error that you get. Could you provide that in your question?

Comment: why do you need TaskCollection? why don't you put the list of Tasks directly to User?

Comment: It doesnt give any error, it just does not create the join table.

Comment: Because I want to reuse this TaskCollection class in other entities, so I won't duplicate code.

Comment: @Mari did you try removing the `Id` annotation from the embeddable class?